# Firefox webpage button names not showing properly

Tags: firefox, icons

I am running Kubuntu LT 20.04. Firefox is version 102.0 64-bit. The font is DejaVu Serif. In webpages where there are navigation buttons like dropdown menus or for expanding menus, the buttons have strange names. The buttons sometimes look a bit like little Q codes, at other times just a capital letter. I've linked to an image to show this behavior.

Could this be because there is some font missing? I've tried refreshing the font cache (`sudo fc-cache -fv`) and a restart, but no improvement.

[image]

Has anyone ever seen this behavior?

Comment: I found the problem: one of my ad blockers, uBlock Origin, was blocking "remote fonts". When I unchecked that setting, the proper navigation icons appeared.

Comment: If you have a solution, add the details *as an answer*, not a comment. It's allowed (and encouraged) to answer your own question. Thanks for your contribution to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: one of my ad blockers, uBlock Origin, was blocking "remote fonts". When I unchecked that setting, the proper navigation icons appeared.